# Text.Split after int (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, text, split

How can I split in C# this user input:

> I am 20

to get this in a String array:

```
"I am " //=varname[0]
"20" //=varname[1]
```

Is it possible to handle it with RegularExpressions?

Comment: What is your pattern? Always before last space or something?

Comment: provide some more test cases to clearly make us understand the pattern

Comment: The number in one String and the other part **with whitespace** in another string

Comment: Why does this question have the `C#` tag?

Answer (score 2):

If your pattern is *always* to get before last space and the rest.. You can use just regular [`String` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods.aspx) such as [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) like;

```
string s = "I am 20";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)); // I am
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1));    // 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it's possible through regex. Just split the input string according to the zero width boundary exists before the digit and it must be  after to the space.

```
(?<= )(?=\d+)
```

**Code:**

```
string value = "I am 20";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"(?<= )(?=\d+)");
 foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**Output:**

```
I am 
20
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/XrTOpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)(?=(\d+))
```

See demo.This works

http://regex101.com/r/kX7cS8/1

Comment: a simple `(.* )(\d+)` will does this job. Op is asking about splitting not matching or capturing.